# Multiple Object Properties JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Got this code snippet in JavaScript which defines multiple properties into an object.

```
var book = {};

Object.defineProperties(book , {
    _year: {
        value: 2004
    },

    edition: {
        value: 1
    },

    year: {
        get: function() {
            return this._year;
        },

        set: function(newValue) {
            if (newValue > 2004) {
                this._year = newValue;
                this.edition += newValue - 2004;
            }
        }
    }
});

book.year = 2005;
alert(book.edition);
```

So the book which has that code claims that `alert(book.edition);`would display `2`.Instead , it displays `1`. Seems like it never executes the part of the accessors property code `(year: get: set:)`. Anyone knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`edition` has been defined as a non-writable property -- the `writable` descriptor property hasn't been specified and is `false` by default. Hence `this.edition += ...` fails silently. The same applies to the `_year` property as well.

```
_year: {
    writable: true,
    value: 2004
},
edition: {
    writable: true,
    value: 1
},
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dz67j/1/)

**Note:** assigning to a non-writable property throws an error in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode), so you can add the `'use strict';` pragma to spot these errors more easily.

Reference:

- [MDN - `Object.defineProperties()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)
- [MDN - `Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) -- explains descriptors more in-depth.

Comment: I would ask a refound! +1

Comment: Should i add `'use strict;'` on top of my script , just above `var book = {};` or above `Object.defineProperties(book , {` , to test this error in `strict mode`? i noticed that script throws an error if i put `'use strict;'` above `var book = {};` , but if i place it above `Object.defineProperties(book , {` it still executes , gives a result of `1` and no error is thrown. On the other hand , if i place it just below `Object.defineProperties(book , {` script never executes even if i put `writable: true` on both properties (_year and edition).This is really confusing

Comment: @user3649693 the `'use strict';` pragma must be the first statement in a script (to apply to the entire script) or the first statement in a function (to apply to that individual function) -- see the [Invoking strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode#Invoking_strict_mode) section for details. Also, don't enable it for an entire script file if that file will later be concatenated with other script files, prefer wrapping the script's code into an IIFE with strict mode enabled in that case.

Comment: @user3649693 and in case you're not familiar with IIFEs, see [this article](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) by Ben Alman.

Comment: Guess i cant put `"use script";` on top of `Object.defineProperties(book , {` method as well right? just on top of a file and on top of a function , is that so?

Comment: @user3649693 exactly. And if you put it on top of a script, then strict mode is enabled for the entire script, including all of its functions -- specifying it per-function is redundant then as strict mode is already enabled for the entire script.